# Retrieve Log In username and output initials based on a table in Access database

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I'm improving an old Access database used to log our receiving inspection reports.

There is a textbox in the report labeled "Inspector Initials". A technician, who has now left the company, wrote a code to retrieve the username and output their initials as a default value.

I tried to recover the database built with it but I can not find it.
I tried formulas and macros to pull this data.
I tried codes that found one other sites/forums.

This used to work.

```vb
Function UserNameWindows() As String
     UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
End Function
```

I would like to retrieve the login username through Outlook, reference the "Initials" table and output that user's initials.

Comment: [Option Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) would have shown`UserNameWindows()<>UserName`, function renamed?

Answer (score 0):

with the assumption that you are using active directory (which is standard in most business environments)

```
Public Function UserNameWindows() As String
    With GetObject("LDAP://" & CreateObject("ADSystemInfo").Username)
        UserNameWindows = .samaccountname
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Yes we are using active directory.  the function above does not input the inspectors username. instead it leaves the cell blank. I have tried to implement this through OnDirty () and AferUpdate () while referencing a new record.